# Calculate side of a polygon that touches another feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, measurements, calculate-values

How can I measure the length of the side of a polygon that touches another feature (calculate from A to B on the image below)?

I'm creating and measuring lines to figure out the lenght of the 'intersection' and I wish that was a easier method using a geoprocessing tool.

How can it be done?

I don't have programing skills and I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

[image: How to calculate point A to B]

Comment: Convert features to line, intersect lines with a snapping tolerance, calculate length of intersect

Comment: If you use output_type = "LINE" then Intersect with two polygon feature classes should give you the line(s) where they intersect in a new feature class where you can read off lengths from the attribute table.